# Keep getting HTTP code 422, not sure whats wrong with the json payload

Tags: json, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am making a python module that interacts with Carousell using the requests module. Now I am trying to send a post request with a JSON payload, but I keep getting HTTP error code 422(UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY). I don't know what's wrong with my JSON payload, python dict(before it's converted to JSON) or perhaps I am missing something in my request headers.

I tried taking the raw json string(from the POST request that I captured using Chrome dev tools) converting it dict and copy that dict(printed out) and try to use it in the program. It didn't work.

```py
login_session = requests.session()
login_session.headers.update({"DNT":"1", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36", "Origin":"https://sg.carousell.com"})
login_payload = {'requests': {'g0': {'resource': 'sso', 'operation': 'create', 'params': {'loginToken': cookies["login-token"]}, 'body': {}}}, 'context': {'_csrf': cookies["_csrf"]}}
login_cookies = {"__cfduid": cookies["__cfduid"], "_csrf": cookies["_csrf"], "gtkprId": cookies["gtkprId"], "login-token": cookies["login-token"], "redirect":"redirect"}
login_headers = {'accept':'*/*','accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br','accept-language':'en-GB,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
login_data = login_session.post(query_url, cookies=login_cookies, data=json.dumps(login_payload), headers=login_header)
```

Heres the output from debugging logger

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://sg.carousell.com:443 "POST /ui/iso?_csrf=TNZTMZpBdQYgRFFouCF4ELVB HTTP/1.1" 422 0
```

Edit:
Heres the JSON payload which was sent to the server. I am trying to replicate it.

```
{"requests":{"g0":{"resource":"sso","operation":"create","params":{"loginToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NTg1MDQyMjQsImlzcyI6ImxvZ2luLmNhcm91c2VsbC5jb20iLCJzc29pZCI6IkRacG1rd1l1SXAxdDF5U3A2M1RXWExPUTJnWmRFRzBOSHd3d0ZGSm9PSkFvVFFOdGFyNWt0MDMzNm5EVHRudHoiLCJ1c2VyaWQiOiIxNDczMjI3NCJ9.x7YxdLLk1ID6_jWy4trtLzbrPnZZ0eI7g_cQN1BilF8"},"body":{}}},"context":{"_csrf":"hPPhgajp-1GMLSbgjZBNBD7z2EGPVGCuA_mU"}}
```

Note that login token and _csrf are data from the cookies.

Comment: Seem like you make a meaningless (semantically) request. Try to check step-by-step business logic of your code.

Comment: For example: I am not quite sure why your body is equal to empty JSON. May be it is correct though: I don't know the api.

Comment: @Artem well this is technically not an API. I am just trying to replicate the HTTP requests my computer sends to the server when I press that login button. i editted my question with the JSON payload captured using chrome dev tools